# Slim3 how can I manage mixed content type errors

Tags: http-headers, content-type, slim-3

I need to set up a Slim application for html and json contents.
I will have just one errorhandler and it is supposed to reply as json for json enpoints and html error page for html views.
In the old fashined Slim (v.2) I have defined the view at the begining of the route, so I could check the view type (twig or json) to understand how to reply.

With the new Slim3 implementation the view will be send at the end of the route and, as far as I know, there is no way to define it earlier.

How can I manage this mixed content errors?

I thought to use the request content type header, but there is not a real rule that the content type should be coherent with the response, for example I can send some request as application/json and get a text/html reply, I also cannot use the Accept header because it can be missing or general `*/*`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depends how you decide, between returning json format or html.

For example, you may return error in json format when it is requested from AJAX otherwise you return html.

If you have error handler that returns html like following code

```
<?php namespace Your\App\Name\Space\Errors;

class HtmlErrorHandler
{

    public function __invoke($request, $response, $exception)
    {
        $err = '<html><head></head><body>' .
            '<div>code : ' . $exception->getCode() . 
            ' message' . $exception->getMessage() '</div>';
        return $response->withStatus(500)
            ->withHeader('content-Type : text/html')
            ->write($err);
    }
}
```

and error handler that returns json,

```
<?php namespace Your\App\Name\Space\Errors;

class JsonErrorHandler
{    
    public function __invoke($request, $response, $exception)
    {
        $err = (object) [
            'code' => $exception->getCode(),
            'message' => $exception->getMessage(),
        ];
        return $response->withStatus(500)->withJson($err);
    }
}
```

You can compose them in another error handler class which select which error handler to return error response based on whether request coming from AJAX for not.

```
<?php namespace Your\App\Name\Space\Errors;

class Http500Error
{
    private $jsonErrorHandler;
    private $htmlErrorHandler;

    public function __construct($jsonErrHandler, $htmlErrHandler) 
    {
        $this->jsonErrorHandler = $jsonErrHandler;
        $this->htmlErrorHandler = $htmlErrHandler;
    }

    public function __invoke($request, $response, $exception)
    {
        if ($request->isXhr()) {
            $errHandler = $this->jsonErrorHandler;
        } else {
            $errHandler = $this->htmlErrorHandler;        
        }
        return $errHandler($request, $response, $exception);
    }
}
```

Or you may put certain variable in query string to indicate which format client want, then you can use

```
if ($request->getParam('format', 'html') === 'json') {
    $errHandler = $this->jsonErrorHandler;
} else {
    $errHandler = $this->htmlErrorHandler;        
}
```

Then you injects error handler to container

```
use Your\App\Name\Space\Errors;
...
$app = new \Slim\App();
$c = $app->getContainer();
$c['errorHandler'] = function ($c) {
    return new Http500Error(new JsonErrorHandler(), new HtmlErrorHandler());
};
```